# to.have.been.calledWith is not a function error in chai#3.5.0

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai

I've updated the version of chai in my project and after updating it to `3.5.0`, some tests are failing. I see that I'm not able to test arguments of the function for which I did spy.

I created a fiddle to reproduce my issue with sample method here - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5z5w0zy/128/)

```
describe('Mocha + Chai JsFiddle', function() {

  it('should test arg', function() {
    var spy = sinon.spy(test, 'testFun');

    test.testFun(5);

    expect(spy).to.have.been.called.with(5);
  });
});
```

Can anyone suggest how can we test argument in newer version chai.js?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you are using Sinon, you can either use the Sinon spy methods and check the results with Chai:

```
expect(spy.calledWith(5)).to.equal(true);
```

Or you can use [sinon-chai](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai) which will let you do:

```
expect(spy).to.have.been.calledWith(5);
```

[See a JSFiddle of the first example](https://jsfiddle.net/c5z5w0zy/129/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to include the sinon-chai.js?
Here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zjet0432/1/
I only added the sinon-chai.js and change your last line to `expect(spy).to.have.been.calledWith(5);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TypeScript with Sinon and Chai and want to use nice `calledWith` assertions in Chai, use `sinon-chai` imports like this:

```js
import chai, {expect} from 'chai'
import sinon from 'ts-sinon'
import sinonChai from 'sinon-chai' // <--- NOTE
```

then configure chai with:

```js
chai.use(sinonChai)
```

and then use assertions like:

```js
let send = sinon.spy()
...
expect(send).to.have.been.calledWithExactly('Greetings!')
```

[Runnable example here](https://github.com/aellerton/vue-ts-yarn1-monorepo) (disclaimer: my own repo)